# Pygame - Issues with button rendering

Tags: python, pygame

Basically, I want to create a button and write text on it with pygame and I succeed.

But the last button (named leaderboardButton) doesn't change image to "./image/mouseOnButton.png" when the cursor is on the button.

I really wonder why is this happening. The rest of button is fine.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 700))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()

class Button():
    def __init__(self, msg, font, x , y, w, h, color):
        self.msg = msg
        self.font = font
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.color = color

    def createButton(self):
        (mouseX, mouseY) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if((mouseX >= self.x and mouseY <= self.x + self.w) and (mouseY >= self.y and mouseY <= self.y + self.h)):
            button = pygame.image.load("./image/mouseOnButton.png")
        else:
            button = pygame.image.load("./image/button.png")
        screen.blit(button, (self.x, self.y))
        text = pygame.font.SysFont(self.font, 32)
        textSurface = text.render(self.msg.encode("utf-8"), True, self.color)
        screen.blit(textSurface, (self.x + self.w / len(self.msg), self.y + self.h / 2))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if(event.key == pygame.K_F4 and pygame.KMOD_ALT):
                sys.exit()

    localButton = Button("Local Play", "./font/NanumSquareRoundEB.ttf", 325, 200, 150, 75, (255, 255, 255)).createButton()
    socketButton = Button("Socket Play", "./font/NanumSquareRoundEB.ttf", 325, 325, 150, 75, (255, 255, 255)).createButton()
    howtoButton = Button("How to Play", "./font/NanumSquareRoundEB.ttf", 325, 450, 150, 75, (255, 255, 255)).createButton()
    leaderboardButton = Button("Leaderboard", "./font/NanumSquareRoundEB.ttf", 325, 575, 150, 75, (255, 255, 255)).createButton()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by a typo in the second line of your `createButton` method (it would be better to use [pygame.Rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)s and their collision detection methods):

```
if((mouseX >= self.x and mouseY <= self.x + self.w) and (mouseY >= self.y and mouseY <= self.y + self.h)):
# Should be:
if((mouseX >= self.x and mouseX <= self.x + self.w) and (mouseY >= self.y and mouseY <= self.y + self.h)):
```

I suggest to create instances of your `Button` before the while loop and also give them a `draw` and a `handle_event` method, so that you can just call `button.draw(screen)` inside of the while loop. I've already modified the Button in the following example. Note that you can simplify your code by using `pygame.Rect`s as the blit position and for the collision detection. You can also put the buttons into a list and draw them and handle the events in a for loop, e.g. `for button in button_list: button.draw(screen)`.

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 700))


class Button():
    def __init__(self, msg, font, x, y, w, h, color):
        self.msg = msg
        self.color = color
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(font, 32)
        self.text_surf = self.font.render(self.msg, True, self.color)
        self.image_normal = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image_normal.fill(pygame.Color('dodgerblue1'))
        self.image_hover = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image_hover.fill(pygame.Color('lightskyblue'))

        self.image = self.image_normal
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        # To center the text rect.
        self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.image = self.image_hover
            else:
                self.image = self.image_normal

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)


local_button = Button(
    "Local Play", "Comic Sans MS", 325, 200, 150, 75, (255, 255, 255))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        local_button.handle_event(event)

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    local_button.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: I can understand your code but I still don't know what was the problem.
It's because optimization or something?

Comment: Oh, it seems that was just a typo in the second line of the `createButton` method: `(mouseX >= self.x and mouseY <= self.x + self.w)` ... `mouseY` should be `mouseX`.

Comment: I was so dumb... thank you for your kindness and additional tips!